# Make table rows stack at the top of a table with a fixed height (leave unused space empty, table rows are dynamic)

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

[Link to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mapr8axj/1/)

```
<table class="cr-table">
<thead class="cr-th">
    <tr>
        <th>Your Item #</th>
        <th>Product Description</th>
        <th>U of M</th>
        <th>Qty Ordered</th>
        <th>Qty Shipped</th>
        <th>Unit Price</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="cr-tbody">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="7">
          <span>Pre-text</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="padding:0px;margin:0px">
      <td><span>Code</span></td>
      <td><span>Name</span></td>
      <td><span>UoS id</span></td>
      <td><span>Qty Ordered</span></td>
      <td><span>Qty Shipped</span></td>
      <td><span>Price</span></td>
      <td><span>Subtotal</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="padding:0px;margin:0px">
      <td><span>Code</span></td>
      <td><span>Name</span></td>
      <td><span>UoS id</span></td>
      <td><span>Qty Ordered</span></td>
      <td><span>Qty Shipped</span></td>
      <td><span>Price</span></td>
      <td><span>Subtotal</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="7">
          <span>Post-text</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

css:

```
    .cr-table {
width: 100% !important; height: 50%; font-size: 11px !important; border: 1px solid black !important;
padding:0px !important;margin: 0px !important;
}
.cr-tbody {border: 1px solid black !important; font-size: 11px; height: 50%; border-collapse: collapse;}
.cr-th {font-size: 13px;border: 1px solid black; color: white; background-color: #829BAE;}
.cr-title {font-size: 22px; text-align: right; margin-right: 5%; font-weight: bold }
.cr-cell-name {font-size: 11px;background-color: #829BAE; border: 1px solid black; color: white; text-align: center}
.cr-cell-content {font-size: 11px; border: 1px solid black; text-align:center;}
.cr-td-foot {border-top: 0px;border-bottom:0px;border-right: solid black 1px;font-size: 11px;padding:3px}
.cr-td-foot-ri {border-top: 0px;border-bottom:0px;font-size: 11px;padding:3px}
.cr-address {padding-left: 0px; font-size: 11px; padding-top: 7px; padding-bottom: 7px; text-align: left !important}
.cr-ref {border: 2px solid red;}
.cr-top {border: 0px}
.cr-empty {color: white}
table.fixed { border-collapse: collapse; page-break-inside: avoid; table-layout:fixed; border: 1px solid black; width: 100% }
table.fixed td { overflow: hidden; border-collapse: collapse; }
```

I've added a link to a jsfiddle, where I've stripped down my code to a more simple example. Basically the rows with "Code Name UoSid etc.." are invoice lines and there can be one or more. I need the table to be of a certain size, but the rows should always be compactly stacked from the top down. In the jsfiddle you can see that they take up the whole table space and spread out evenly. In the masterpiece below you can see what I have on the left and what I need on the right.
[image: On the left is what I have, on the right is what I need]

Comment: Your fiddle does not match this code pasted: `.cr-table {
width: 100% !important; height: 50%; ` - remove that height in the fiddle (it says 200px there) and it spaces the rows as you describe.

Comment: Yeah, sorry bout that, but I need it to be of a specific height. In the pic I drew, I show both tables of the same size but the rows are stacked right next to each other at the top in the right one, with any left over space being left blank.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing to apply style for TD in body of table.  I would like to suggest you to option to solve issue :

If you want text-align left from top to down then add this to css :

```
.cr-tbody td{border-left:2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0);}
```

If you want text to be center in each td then add this to css:

```
.cr-tbody td{border-left:2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0);text-align:center;}
```

Hope this help you to solve your issue.

Comment: There are styles in there not used in this example, because I just copy pasted the css for my whole qweb report, but I only posted the code for the table (also incomplete and stripped, because it's not really just html, it's qweb). And this doesn't help solve the issue, alignment of content inside the cells is not a problem, it's the rows themselves that are spread out.